# Primeiras Letras do nome completo

Tags: html

Gostaria que quando o usuario digitasse no input do Nome Completo aparecesse assim
ex:
João Alves
com as 2 primeiras iniciais maiusculas

Agradeço.

Código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

É só utilizar a propiedade *text-transform* do CSS

> Diretamente no HTML

```
<input style="text-transform:capitalize"....
```

> Por um arquivo .css

```
tag{
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajda

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a propriedade "text-transform: capitalize;" em seu css.